# Authorization on another site when the script is running

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I write a function in a script, after clicking on a link to an another  site, will indicate there authorization data and click on the Login button. At the moment, because of this, the script returns a response:  `Exception: Failed to send a request to the service https: // ... Error code: 401.`

Comment: please see [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

try checking out [this site](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/401-unauthorized-error) which has a lot of information. I'll Include the summery here:

The 401 Unauthorized Error is an HTTP response status code indicating that the request sent by the client could not be authenticated. This is similar yet distinctly different from the 403 Forbidden Error we looked at in a previous article, which indicates that authentication may have been provided by the client, but the client is still not permitted to access the requested resource. Conversely, a 401 Unauthorized Error indicates that the requested resource is restricted and requires authentication, but the client failed to provide any such authentication.

As with most HTTP response codes, particularly those that indicate an error, the appearance of a 401 Unauthorized Error can be a challenge to properly diagnose and resolve. With a potential pool of over 50 status codes that represent the complex relationship between the client, a web application, a web server, and often multiple third-party web services, determining the cause of a particular status code can be a challenge under the best of circumstances.

In this article we’ll examine the 401 Unauthorized Error in more detail by looking at what might cause a message, along with a handful of tips for diagnosing and debugging this error your own application. We’ll even examine a number of the most popular content management systems (CMSs) for potential problem areas that could cause your own website to be generating a 401 Unauthorized Error